# How can i replace a specific string within a line inside a text file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, replace

```
$ cat text.txt
my name is Steven
my age is 10
i like dogs
```

What command will be fitting so that `echo "Kate"` will replace `Steven` on `text.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

If it must be with `echo "Kate"`, use `awk`:

```
echo "Kate" | awk 'NR==FNR{a=$0;next} sub("Steven", a, $0)1' - file
```

- The standard input is `Kate` from `echo "Kate"`, piped to `awk`.
- `awk` then reads the stdin (`-`). The condition `NR==FNR` is true when the first file is processes (stdin). The variable `a` is set to that value.
- Then the input of `file` is processed and `sub()` replaces `Steven` with the value of `a`.
- the `sub()1` is the pattern in the statement and will always return true whether a substitution occurs or not. There is no action, which is equivalent to `{ print }`, so each line is printed after being substituted.

But, better would be to use `sed`, just:

```
sed 's/Steven/Kate/' file
```

If you want to make  the changes in place within the file, use

```
sed -i 's/Steven/Kate/' file
```